# ios swift reactive programming

Tags: ios, swift

Not sure the best way to phrase the question, but I'll give it a try.
I have a button, whose visibility is directly tied to a state variable in my model. When that state variable is true, I want the button to be visible, and when that state variable is false, I want the button to be invisible.

Is there a native way in swift that ties the rendering of a button directly to a state variable? My work around is creating a function, toggle state, that ties the state change and the button visibilities together, but it really seems the button visibility ought to be reactive on the state.

Comment: didn't exactly get your question, you can use button.hidden property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have a reference to your view from your model, perhaps via an interface, you can define your state variable like this:

```
var stateVar: Bool {
   didSet {
      // note that we are referencing our own variable here.
      self.delegate.setButtonHidden(self.stateVar)  
   }
}
```

I'd recommend using the framework [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) though. It supports what you are trying to do, without interfacing.

Comment: Little improvement: `delegate.setButtonHidden(stateVar) `

Comment: Just wanted to point out that i was using the variable itself within the didSet.

Comment: one question how would you give the stateVar a default value without an initializer for the class?

Comment: var stateVar: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            
        }
    }